# Can eggs be earned when inventory is full?

Tags: pokemon-go

Once the inventory cap is reached, a message pops up saying that your inventory is full.

But can eggs still be obtained when this is the case?

Comment: Since you get an error when spinning the Pokéstop with full inventory you probably can't collect eggs, even if there is room for them. I didn't receive an egg when I tried to spin Pokéstops with full inventory and one open egg slot. This could have been bad luck as well, so I don't post it as answer.

Comment: @dly experiencing the same. Not sure whether it is bad luck, a bug, or intended behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain eggs from pokéstops only when you have free bag space (when you actually receive items from the pokéstop) even when you have empty slots for eggs. I usually discard revives to stay slightly below the cap until I have 9/9 eggs again.

Source: personal experience